# Calling API from python azure function with managed identity

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-functions, azure-managed-identity

I am trying to use a python azure function to call an API running on an Azure app service.
(I have managed to get the webAPI to call the function-trigger (managed-identity and all that), but the function needs data that can be retrieved from the API.)

In order to simplify authentication, my thought is to use the managed-identity within the python function and create a JWT that accompanies the requests.

```
credential = DefaultAzureCredential()
token = credential.get_token("api://<APPLICATION_ID>/.default")
// make call to API using token as authorization
// response 200
```

This currently works. APPLICATION_ID is registered within Azure AD.

It feels wrong to request a token, using the functions APPLICATION_ID as a scope. When the API in reality has nothing to do with it. But my attempts at using any other scope is met with errors.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the service/resource you want to access that decides the scope.

e.g. if you want to access storage, the scope is "https://storage.azure.com/.default".

(I work in Microsoft Azure SDK team)

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply. My issue is that I want to call my own .NET web-api using a token from the function, your suggested scope works (same result as "api.../.default" from above). I get an identityprovider and nameidentifier claim, and I can work with that. It was more if there was a better scope to use for custom api scope tokens. ```https://graph.microsoft.com/.default``` does not work

Comment: Scope is registered in your app configuration.

I believe https://graph.microsoft.com/.default is used by graph service and we cannot register it in our apps.